# ExceptionMapper in Jersey throws mapMappableContainerException

Tags: java, rest, exception, jersey

I have created one Rest services and wanted to implement exception handling but it throws mapMappableContainerException while i try to run the services. You can find my code here.

MyService :

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("add")
public Response addJobSeeker() throws MyCustomException{

    throw new MyCustomException("My Exception");    

}
```

My Exception class.

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper extends Exception implements ExceptionMapper<MyCustomException>{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public MyExceptionMapper(String str){
        super(str);
    }
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MyCustomException exception) {
        System.out.println("In my exception mapper -- "+exception.getMessage());
        Success sc = new Success(404, "Hello", "I am mukesh");
        return Response.status(404).entity(sc).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();        
    }

}
```

MyCustomClass

```
public class MyCustomException extends Exception {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public MyCustomException(String str){
        super(str);
    }
```

Comment: The generic parameter type of `ExceptionMapper` should be your exception type. Since your mapper extends Exception, you should throw MyExceptionMapper instead of MyCustomException, or make the generic type MyCustomException instead

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for response i tried as per your suggestion also edited question still i am fetching same issue.

Comment: How are you even registering the mapper? It only has a constructor that excepts the exception message? You should not implement your mapper this way. Just use your custom exception as the generic type, and get rid of that constructor

Comment: Still not he the rid. I update my code and question according to your suggestion still fetching same issue i don't know why :(

Comment: 1. Don't make the mapper extend Exception. 2. Make the generic type of the mapper your custom exception, ie. `ExceptionMapper<MyCustomException>`. 3. Throw your custom exception. 4. Get rid of that constructor in your mapper. It need's a default constructor. 5. Make sure the mapper is being registered. You can add a simple s.o.p in the constructor to check